# how to call a remote fabric method in django

Tags: python, django, fabric

I need to call a fabric method on a remote machine through django. I mean when user send a given request get the hostname of a remote machine.
Something like this:

```
def get_hostname(request):  
  hostname = os.system('fab remote_server hostname')  
  return hostname
```

Comment: sorry don t know how to format it properly :(

Comment: I can't make the edit as I don't have enough reputation, but if you highlight the text and click on the button with brackets, that will format your code correctly.

Comment: Is your difficulty in making the fabric call (in which case this isn't really a Django question), or in using Django to get the right parameters for it?

Comment: I just wanna call the fabric method as a python function

Comment: no there is no error but I have to use execute method and there is no way to capture the output

Comment: Are you trying to get the hostname of the user's computer, or the domain name of the ip address they are accessing your server from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For greater control and flexibility you should use fabric as a library. see: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/usage/library.html

```
import fabric.api as fab
from fabric.network import disconnect_all
from contextlib import contextmanager

@context_manager
def ssh(settings):
    with settings:
         try:
            yield
         finally:
            disconnect_all()

def hostname(request, host='somehost', user='someuser', pw='secret'):  
    with ssh(fab.settings(host_string=host, user=user, password=pw)):
         return fab.run('hostname')
```

Comment: will I be able to catch the out put this way ?

Comment: just the output of the command i wanna know if the command executed successfully or not?

Comment: 'run' will return an attribute string that has a "succeeded" attribute on it set to True for checking that the command executed successfully.  You may wish to wrap your run call with the settings context manager with 'warn_only=True' to avoid fabric attempting to exit (the default behavior).

Answer (score 1):

If you server has the needed parts for fabric you should be able to just import you fabfile on call the function directly.

(This is just some code I dreamt up YMMW)

```
import fabfile as f #Your fabfile must be somewhere it can be imported


def get_hostname(request):  
  hostname = f.remote_server(hostname)
  return hostname
```

You can also import and use fabric directly from django

Answer (score 0):

Check `fabric.tasks.execute()` after version 1.3.