# Django to make an app to manage a linux server

Tags: django, django-channels

I would like to use django to make an app to manage my linux server.

I'll need to execute script and get the result.
Do you thinks websoket and Django Channel ( https://github.com/django/channels ) are a good solution ?

Or I missing something and there is a better way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Fabric? It's usually used as a command line tool. http://www.fabfile.org/

You could build an app in Django that calls Fabric commands. That will get you working at a high level very quickly.
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/library.html

[how to call a remote fabric method in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799149/how-to-call-a-remote-fabric-method-in-django)

Comment: thanks very interesting ! I think that tornado or cyclone could be great too.